# How to create Animation like Path Application in Android

Tags: android

How to create Animations like Path Application in Android. Is there any demos or tutorial for the same.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.path&hl=en

Animation like this url :-

[http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WODUdDT2m-s](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.path&hl=en)

Comment: first tell us about Path Application. at least provide link here

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.path&hl=en

Comment: you can check and reply now if you can..ok can you ??  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WODUdDT2m-s

Answer (score 18):

There are some open source projects that have implemented it.

https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu

https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu

Have fun!!

Comment: Awesome man.!! You really made me feel that..Android can beat iPhone..Thanks

Comment: How to implement ArcMenu? Is it an Android Library project?

Comment: Cooool.. thanks for the link.. a quick question, any idea on how to place the button in the center of the screen, and the icons coming out surrounds it?

Comment: Can you tell how is that watch implemented when the page scrolls it also moves with that