# CustomizedView in android - listView and Button UI

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, android-custom-view

i'm trying to develop the given UI in android, there is a ListView and on top of it a button is visible , listView's height is Fill_PARENT and button is fix at it's position.

How to add a view above of a view? or any idea about creating this layout using XML or customizedView.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think from what i understand in your question it seems like you are looking for `FrameLayout`. So there is a list view and top of it is a button. Right? Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/mainlayout" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ListView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:padding="10dp" android:id="@+id/myListView"/>

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/buttondrawable" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for the clue i'm using FrameLayout as an parent it might seems to be working.

Comment: by the way by any chance, are you doing something similar to (Path App) like button? - Just out of my curiosity!

Comment: @Wesley : do you have any idea or code about how to do like the button Add at the bottom of the Path App ??

Comment: @Wesley : if you want more perfect solutions for that button of path app ; see this thread ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922127/how-to-create-animation-like-path-application-in-android , enjoy ;)

Comment: Thanks, I've seen those too :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to create your layout for your item , and ovverride the `BaseAdapter` to create your own adapter for your custom `ListView` ,

see this [tutorial](http://www.mubasheralam.com/tutorials/android/listview-custom-layout-rows) to learn how to create a custom `ListView`

see this question it is similar to your case : [how to customize listview row android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407865/how-to-customize-listview-row-android)

and finally , this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) is very good and it manage the selection states for your list items  :

Comment: my question is not related with ListView adapter, i have to display the Button above the listView.it's like adding a view in the subView of another view in iOS.

Comment: you want to have a button above your listView ??? so add it in your xml layout , i didn't understand what you really want :)

Comment: yes the button should be above the listView.how's it is possible using xml layout or runtimeView.

Comment: i don't know if you want that your button should be visible all the time above your listView, so you don't need to add it on runtime , simply add it on the layout xml , by using a RelativeLayout , and place your ListView bellow the button :)